# How to restore a file content which wasn't saved properly?

Tags: files, restore

Somehow several days ago I didn't save a very important .txt file draft and now this file is empty. What to do to restore its content, because I can't seem actually to google a solution ?

Comment: how were you editing the file? Most likely it is unrecoverable, but the editor you were using may have stored a temp file somewhere...

Comment: via terminal, in nano.

Comment: check for the existence of a .save or .swp file in the same directory as the .txt. For example, if your file is called `filename.txt`, check for `filename.txt.swp` or `filename.txt.save`.